# Set the dialog box text in jquery

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, html, css

I am new to jquery and I am stuck on a problem. I am trying to design a web page containing four images and i want a dialog box to popup showing the details of the current image that was clicked. However, i cannot get the text in the dialog box to change and it always shows the details of the first image.

A number is set in a hidden field to identify which image was clicked, and this is then used by the GetDetail1() and GetDetail2() functions to  return a string with the appropriate details.
Heres the script:

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" Id="JavascriptValue" value="1"/>
<div id="dialog-block">
<b>Detail1:</b>
<table border="0">
    <tr>
    <td><% =GetDetail1() %></td>
    <td colspan="2">
        <img src="Assets\people\silhoeutte1.jpg" width="100" height="100" style="padding-left: 100px;" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><b>Detail2:</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><% =GetDetail2() %></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
// the jQuery document ready handler
$(function () {
    var name;
    // create our dialog
    $('#dialog-block').dialog({
    title: '<%=GetImageName()%>',
    oneInstance: false,
    autoOpen: false,
    width: 400,
    buttons: {
        "Close": function () {
        closeDialog($(this))
        }
    }
    });

// the images to open the dialog
$('#image1,#image3,#image2,#image4').click(function (event) {
    if (this.id == 'image1') {
    document.forms['form1'].JavascriptValue.value = "1"; //set the value
    $('#dialog-block').dialog('open');
    }
    else if (this.id == 'image2') {
    document.forms['form1'].JavascriptValue.value = "2"; //set the value
    $('#dialog-block').dialog('open');
    }
    else if (this.id == 'image3') {
    document.forms['form1'].JavascriptValue.value = "3";//set the value
    $('#dialog-block').dialog('open');
    }
    else if (this.id == 'image4') {
    document.forms['form1'].JavascriptValue.value = "4"; //set the value
    $('#dialog-block').dialog('open');
    }
});
});

function closeDialog(elem) {
    elem.dialog("close");
}
</script>
```

GetDetail Functions

```
public String GetDetails1()
{
    List<User> imagelist = DatabaseAccessor.getImagesFromDataBase();
    return imagelist[Convert.ToInt32(JavascriptValue.Value)].Detail;
}
```

Comment: Try generating a loop to get all the GetDetails data first and then assign an id to each items and then you can open them with dialog of those ids.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem lays in these lines 
`document.forms['form1'].JavascriptValue.value`.
You need to do it like this `document.getElementById("JavascriptValue").value`. Your hidden field is set default to one, that's why you getting details of 1st image always.

Comment: When i did the change you suggested, Visual Studio shows the following error: JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'getElementById'

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Edited answer.

Comment: it really doesn't change anything still :(. Im thinking there is something wrong with my getDetailFunction?

Comment: @misterMan so you should tell me if there is something wrong with your functions :) You need to run it in Debug mode and see which bit is `null`